# How to color the background of a canvas coordinate grid on click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

How to select multiple squares and on click change their background color on a canvas with javascript?

So far I am able to "draw" the canvas and the coordinate grid. The part I am not able to figure out is how to change the background color of a selected square and how to do the same thing with multiple squares (selecting them with the mouse)?

```js
function draw() {

      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        for(var x=0.5;x<500;x+=10) {
          context.moveTo(x,0);
          context.lineTo(x,500);
        }

        for(var y=0.5; y<500; y+=10) {
          context.moveTo(0,y);
          context.lineTo(500,y);

      }

      context.strokeStyle='grey';
      context.stroke();

  }
}

function color(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - 10;
    var y = event.clientY - 10;
    
    console.log(x + ' ' + y);
    // how to color the selected squares?
  }
```

```css
#canvas { border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<body onload='draw()'>
    <div id=container>
      <canvas id='canvas' width='500' height='500' onclick="color(event)"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to maintain a state. Here I start off creating an two dimensional array (an array of arrays) that holds an object. The state of the object can be selected=true|false.

In the draw() function I iterate the array and set the fillStyle according to the state of the object.

In the color() function I calculate the index of an object and set the selected property to true. And then I draw the canvas again.

```js
var squares = [...new Array(50)].map((a,i) => [...new Array(50)].map((a,i) => {return {selected: false};}));

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
function draw() {
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 501, 501);
    squares.forEach((line, i) => {
      line.forEach((square, j) => {
        context.fillStyle = (square.selected) ? 'red' : 'white';
        context.fillRect(10*j+1, 10*i+1, 9, 9);
      });
    });
  }
}

function color(event) {
  var x = Math.floor((event.clientX - 10) / 10);
  var y = Math.floor((event.clientY - 10) / 10);
  squares[y][x].selected = true;
  draw();
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
```

```html
<body onload='draw()'>
  <div id=container>
    <canvas id='canvas' width='501' height='501' onclick="color(event)"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will start using this practice and use the "states" approach. This is perfect! 

One more thing I was struggling with: Can you point me out in the right direction how to select several squares at once? For example if I want to get 6 or more squares colored at the same time.

Comment: @Don40 A more important question would be: How will the user then interact with the page? Lets say that square 3,4 (row,column) was clicked and you would like the square to the right (3,5) of it also colored. so `squares[3][4].selected = true;squares[3][4+1].selected = true;draw();`